# How to debug the code in Linqpad

Tags: c#, linqpad

Start LINQPad In VS, open Debug -> 
Attach to Process... 
Choose LINQPad.exe 
Set breakpoint in your code called by LINQPad C# code, or write Debugger.Break() in your LINQPad script where you want the debugger to halt. 
Execute the script from LINQPad and watch the magic.

I used the following process to debug my code in LinqPad, but getting the following error :

Visual Studio cannot debug this unhandled exception because it comes form a version of the Microsoft.Net Framework that is newer than the installed version of Visual Studio.
The problem is that I am using LinqPad4 and .Net Framework 4.0.

Can anyone please tell me where I am lacking up??

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio you're using? LINQPad is comfortable debugging with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Yes I am using the same version(VS 2010)

Comment: FYI: This is now available from within the linqpad client \o/

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Framework 4.5 installed? If so, LINQPad will use the C# 5 compiler, in which case you might need VS2012 to debug.

You can test for this by running the following expression in LINQPad:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run (() => 123)
```

If it compiles, then you're on Framework 4.5.

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run (() => 123)
It is giving error "System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run" does not contain a definition of Run. I execute this statement by selecting "C# Statements" from the top.

Comment: And I am sure that in my machine I have latest 2010 version installed.